# OpenVPN+xfreerdp works on Linux Mint but not on ChromeOS - how to debug?

Tags: linux, openvpn, debug, google-chrome-os, xrdp

I work from home and use openvpn to connect to company network, then use xfreerdp to connect to my workstation. It works on Linux Mint. When I copied all the files to my Chromebook, installed the same packages in LDE and tried to connect, it no longer works.

The problem I have is that openvpn doesn't print a single log and xfreerdp prints the same messages as the system that works. How can I:

1. make sure I successfully connected to the company VPN
2. debug the xfreerdp command to see what the problem is

I don't have the access to the server-side configuration/logs, all I have is what I see on my PC. I'm 100% sure there is no limitation on the device I'm connection from, because it works on any other Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

I can use ping to test the VPN connection. I thought it doesn't work but apparently when I was testing it on the Linux Mint, the VPN connection must have been down. This would also explain why I was getting the exact same errors from xfreerdp on Linux Mint and ChromeOS. Now I know that the problem is with openvpn. Not sure if xfreerdp will work when I fix it but at least now I have a place to start.

EDIT1: The reason why openvpn was not loggging anything was --daemon flag, without it, it shows everything that happens.

EDIT2: OpenVPN couldn't connect, because the cipher on the server site was not in cipher list of the client, now it works.